# I keep getting "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing " on Eclipse, how to fix that?

Tags: java, javafx

I followed steps by steps mentioned on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC4XB6JAaoU

So, including:
E(fx)CLIPSE Plugin Installation,
Creating a new JavaFX Project,
Downloading and cofiguring JavaFX,
Creating User Library,
Adding JavaFX to Eclipse,
Configuring Build Path and Arguments

But I still got Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.

My OS is Mac and jdk version is 12.

I don't know what's wrong with that.

Comment: Update to the latest JDK (16 on tuesday), read the official documentation https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ and if that is still not enough watch the corrected version of your above video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk28ytggz7E

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question on the main part itself. **The question should be written so that it makes sense even if the links break or change.** Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.